# Elegant/correct way to call a $http request in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a more elegant/correct way to compose an url with `$http` in AngularJS?

I find my self doing a lot of this:

```
$http.post('/api/' + model_id + '/' + id).success(function(data){
  //do something ..
});
```

and wandering if there was something like this (a little more readable)

```
$http.post('/api/:model_id/:id', {param1, param2}).success(function(data){
  //do something ..
});
```

Thanks

Comment: First of all, `success` is deprecated in favor of the standard `then`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: If your requirement is to consume lightweight REST api, you can use [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). It is wrapper over `$http` that supports the url format that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following pattern:

o in a service called resources I create resources as follows (assuming my webservces are unter the URL path /webapi):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('resources', function ($resource) {
    var baseUrl = location.pathname + 'webapi';
    return {
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      myServiceResource: $resource(baseUrl + '/my/service/:pathParam'),
      myOtherServiceResource: $resource(baseUrl + '/my/other/service')
      // etc.
    };
  });
```

o in a controller or another service you can then simply reference the resources service and use the globally defined resources (which are created only once):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('aService', function (resources) {
    // pathParam matches the parameter :pathParam in the URL
    // param1 and param2 are passed as query parameters
    var parameters = { pathParam: "pathValue", param1: "aValue", param2: "anotherValue" };
    var response = resources.myServiceResource.get(parameters, function() {
        // do something on success
        doSomething(response.result);
      }, function(httpResponse) {
        // do something on error
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with $http directly, but it seems you are looking for $resource (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Example from docs:

```
// Define CreditCard class
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });

// We can retrieve a collection from the server
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
  // GET: /user/123/card
  // server returns: [ {id:456, number:'1234', name:'Smith'} ];

  var card = cards[0];
  // each item is an instance of CreditCard
  expect(card instanceof CreditCard).toEqual(true);
  card.name = "J. Smith";
  // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
  card.$save();
  // POST: /user/123/card/456 {id:456, number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
  // server returns: {id:456, number:'1234', name: 'J. Smith'};

  // our custom method is mapped as well.
  card.$charge({amount:9.99});
  // POST: /user/123/card/456?amount=9.99&charge=true {id:456,         number:'1234', name:'J. Smith'}
});

// we can create an instance as well
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
// POST: /user/123/card {number:'0123', name:'Mike Smith'}
// server returns: {id:789, number:'0123', name: 'Mike Smith'};
expect(newCard.id).toEqual(789);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using resource right now, but i will keep it in mind when i do.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern because it allows me to implement my own error handling logic when API calls is failed, also I found that it is readable and easy to understand.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('myService', function($http, $q) {
    var baseUrl = location.pathname + 'webapi';
      return({
        setService: setService,
        getService: getService
      });

    function setService(param1, param2) {
      var request = $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: baseUrl,
        params: {
          param1: param1,
          param2: param2
        }
      });
      return ( request.then ( handleSuccess, handleError) );
    }

    function getService(param1, param2) {
      var request = $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: baseUrl,
        params: {
          param1: param1,
          param2: param2
        }
      });
      return ( request.then ( handleSuccess, handleError) );
    }  

    function handleError( response ) {
      // Implement our own failure message if there is none
      if ( !angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message) {
        return($q.reject("Failed to get data.") );
      }
      return($q.reject(response.data.message));
    }

    function handleSuccess( response ) {
      return response;
    }
});
```